# SSIS job failing with error “The step did not generate any output. The return value was unknown. The process exit code was -529697949. ”

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssis, sql-agent-job, aceoledb

I have a SSIS Package which has a simple dataflow with Excel to Excel data transfer. I am using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0 driver for connection. Now in my development machine it is running fine through packages. But when I deploy and ran it via SQl agent job it is giving me the error

> The step did not generate any output.  The return value was unknown.  The process exit code was -529697949.

I tried enable the logging and but its not printing any error in the logs.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: First thing to check is that Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0 is installed and well registered in the machine where your package is now running. Other thing  to check is that the same version of ACE and Excel you are using in your dev machine are being used in the new machine.

Comment: I am using ACE OLEDB 16.0 both in dev and prod.

Comment: For Ace OLEDB 12.0 in prod - The step did not generate any output. The return value was unknown. The process exit code was -529697949.                                                                  For Ace OLEDB 16.0 error is -  The process exit code was -1066598274.

Comment: the error for ACE 16 seems related to 64b incompatibility, could be that dev SQL server is running in 64b and prod in 32b. A workaround you could also try is downgrade the excel version, i.e. from xlsx to xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Solution , It was due to desktop Heap Size

Answer (score 0):

My context:
SQL job executing (using on its step an SQL Server proxy related to an account without administration privileges on the local server) a File System SSIS package located in a remote server, where de SSIS package tries to process an Excel file (.xls).

My error:
The step did not generate any output. The return value was unknown. The process exit code was -529697949.

My solution: Granting Full Control privileges on HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Office to the account related to the SQL Server proxy.